# Users experiencing logouts too fast in CakePHP 4

Tags: session, cakephp, logout

My users are experiencing logout too soon (about 15-30 minutes) and I don't get it. I have tried following configuration with no luck. Something else is clearly affecting this as session configuration seem to have no effect. System is running on Linux.

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => '1440',
        'ini' => [
            'session.cookie_lifetime' => 86400
        ]
```

Any ideas where to look for?

Comment: Is your web server's PHP configured to allow overwriting of the cookie lifetime ini value? If you look at the cookie you actually get right after logging in, what's the expiry time on it?

Comment: Hi. When i take a look on session cookie, it is set to expire +1 day from current login moment.